# inheritance of virtual class - the second object type has no method x

Tags: ocaml

I have a virtual super class and a sub class inheriting from it. In the following is a simple example of my situation:

```
class virtual super = object(self)

 method virtual virtualSuperMethod : super

end;;

class sub = object(self)
  inherit super

  method subMethod y =
    y+2;

  method virtualSuperMethod =
    let newSub = new sub in
    newSub

end;;
```

However, when i try to compile i get the following error:

```
Error: The expression "new sub" has type sub but is used with type super
       The second object type has no method subMethod
```

This error disappears when i delete *subMethod*.

As you can see the error message says that one of the problems is that i am returning a sub type. I don't understand why that is a problem, because sub inherits super. And why does it only appear when i add *subMethod*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appear only when you add the method submethod because it makes 
the class sub a subclass ofthe class super, and in OCaml, objects coercion must be explicit :

```
method virtualSuperMethod =
let newSub = new sub in
(newSub :> super)
```

This should fix your problem.

You can have a look at https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/objects.html for more details.

Comment: If your purpose is specifically to copy objects, you can use Oo.copy function. Unfortunatly i'am not familliar with the object part of Ocaml but you can check this for more advanced usage: https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/objectexamples.html#sec37

Answer (score 1):

OCaml does not have implicit coercion between types - you have to insert a explicit coercion, like this:

```
class virtual super = object (self)
 method virtual virtualSuperMethod : super
end

class sub = object (self)
  inherit super
  method subMethod y = y + 2
  method virtualSuperMethod =
    let newSub = new sub in
    (newSub :> super)
end
```

Comment: Right at the same time :)